# For loop in Hogan JS template

Tags: javascript, for-loop, express, mustache, hogan.js

I am using Express JS and Hogan JS template engine. I know hogan is logic less template but I need to **execute a for loop** in view code to generate table fields.

I have done lots of googling but I did not found any solution. I know how to do **if-else** in Hogan JS.

I read all the documentation in [Hogan JS](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) and [Mustache JS](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) websites.

I am getting values in the json format.

```
[
    {
        "email": "abc@example.com",
        "name": "abc",
        "date": "05/01/2015"
    },
    {
        "email": "xyz@example.com",
        "name": "xyz",
        "date": "05/01/2015"
    }
]
```

this is sample json, there may be any amount of data. To show this data in table in view I need to iterate a loop. 
So I need a code for for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly do that.

Assign the data into a nested JSON object and them compile template for parent key.

```
var data = {"list" : [
   {
       "email": "abc@example.com",
       "name": "abc",
       "date": "05/01/2015"
   },
   {
       "email": "xyz@example.com",
       "name": "xyz",
       "date": "05/01/2015"
   }
]};  
var template = Hogan.compile("{{#list}} Your name is {{name}} and email is {{email}} <br/>{{/list}}"); 
var output = template.render(data);
```

Here is the working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LuD6j/45/)