# How to use if statements with in for loop in Hogan js

Tags: node.js, express, hogan.js

I am new in node js.
I am using Express JS and Hogan JS template engine. I know we can not use logic in this template but I need to execute a **if statement** within **for** loop statement in view code, to generate table fields.
I tried so many things, Even I follow this links [**Hogan js**](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) also.

But there is only if or for example is give there is no solution for both at a same time.

My data is in this Form

```
[ 
    { 
     buln_id: 1,
     name: 'Himanshu',
     cname: 'India',
     created_date: 'Tue Jul 07 2015',
     state_name: 'Chandigarh',
     city_name: 'Chandigarh',
     locality_name: 'Behlana',
     office_type_name: 'SCO',
     office_number: '1234',
     floor_no: 'ground floor',
     section: 'a',
     owner_name: 'RAvi',
     mob_no: '123456789',
     email_name: 'aaa@gmail.com',
     web_name: 'sss.com',
     landmark: 'sss',
     bus_info: 'IT',
     service: 'sss',
     pay_details: 'Cash',
     net_surrfing: 'a',
     verification: 1 
     },
     { 
      buln_id: 5,
      name: 'User1',
      cname: 'India',
      created_date: 'Sat Aug 01 2015',
      state_name: 'Chandigarh',
      city_name: 'Chandigarh',
      locality_name: 'Maloya',
      office_type_name: 'SCF',
      office_number: 'a',
      floor_no: 'Ground Floor',
      section: 'a',
      owner_name: 'a',
      mob_no: '123456789',
      email_name: 'a@gmail.com',
      web_name: 'a',
      landmark: 'a',
      bus_info: 'aa',
      service: 'a',
      pay_details: 'cash',
      net_surrfing: 'mobile',
      verification: 1 
      }
```

]

Here I want to generate a table according to the data and where is the verification is 1. i want to put check sign else put cross sign.
Please anyone help me I m new in this field.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You follow this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998595/for-loop-in-hogan-js-template)

Comment: i am already tried this its works only for for loop, I don't know how to insert if in between this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried This

```
 <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Owner Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Bussiness  info</th>
          <th>User</th>
          <th>Created Time</th>
          <th>Verification</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {{#allRecords}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{owner_name}}</td>
          <td>{{office_type_name}}-{{office_number}}, {{locality_name}}
                                {{city_name}}, {{state_name}}, {{cname}}</td>
           <td>{{mob_no}}<br>{{email_name}}</td>
           <td>{{service}}</td>
           <td>{{name}}</td>
           <td>{{created_date}}</td>
           {{#verification}}
           <td><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x green"></i></td>
           {{/verification}}
           {{^verification}}
           <td><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x red"></i></a></td>
           {{/verification}}
         </tr>
           {{/allRecords}}
        </tbody>
     </table>
```